# What if trustStore certificate expires?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, truststore

What excepttions I will/may recive if certificates stored in java trust store expires?
Will I certantly recive exception accessing certified resource? Under what circumstances there will be no exceptions?

Comment: Note Sun-then-Oracle did and still does remove expired or otherwise obsolete root certs from the _default_ truststore ($JRE/lib/security/cacerts) in its Java packages, so this matters only if you (1) use some other Java package (2) don't keep your package up to date (3) add certs to cacerts or (4) use a nondefault truststore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a certificate in the trust store expires, and is not replaces with an updated version with the same subject and key, it will be discarded for the purpose of building the certification path, so you'll get an `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException` (coming from "*PKIX path building failed...*").

If you look at the [JSSE Reference Guide (trust manager section)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#TrustManagerFactory), it relies on the [CertPath API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html) (which implements what's needed to verify the date/time).

The default PKIX trust manager implements [RFC 3280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3280#section-6.1), which requires all certificates in the chain to be valid at the current date/time. See section 6.1:

> The algorithm presented in this section validates the certificate with respect to the current date and time.

and

> (d)  for all x in {1, ..., n}, the certificate was valid at the time in question.

If you want to bypass this, you can implement your own trust manager (although it's generally not recommended, since you'd weaken the default algorithm).

Comment: What if, @Bruno, the trust store contains both the server and the root certificate and only the server certificate expires, what will the behavior be? From your answer it sounds like the server certificate will be discarded and it will NOT throw an exception because it is still able to validate against the root certificate. Is this correct?

Comment: In our environment the leaf certificate (on the end of the chain) is expired but the 3 other certificates (including the root certificate) are not. We are still able to make an SSL connection. So that would seem to confirm @rudolfv 's suspicion.

Comment: @Joman68 If the server certificate has expired, then it should throw an exception. Have you got any custom trust manager in place?

Comment: @Bruno I've just run into a similar situation. Our clients trust store contains the (expired) server certificate, but neither the CA nor the intermediate CA. The connection is accepted. As far as I can see, there's no custom trust manager involved.

Comment: @Bruno I just confirmed with Zulu Java 11: Having only the expired server certificate in the truststore of the client is sufficient to establish a connection.

Comment: The 3280 (and 5280) algorithm defines the path-to-be-validated to _exclude_ the anchor, which need not be a cert at all (and in Java PKIXParameters for a validator can use a KeyStore that contains certs _or_ a Set of TrustAnchor that doesn't). This is confirmed by the paragraph immediately after (d). Thus **(d) does not check the expiration of the anchor even if it is a cert** and has one. LetsEncrypt has used this to support way-old Androids which predate and now can't get the ISRG root by bridging to the DST X3 root even after it expired in 2021 (though they will drop this next year).

Answer (score 2):

I would expect an expired certificate to not be used by the system. So to your code, it should behave as though not found at all.