# How the Java trust manager handles expired TLS certificates

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, truststore

I have a Spring Boot application who connects to several remote resources like: AWS DocumentDB, Salesforce, Outlook.com etc.

To interact with these remote services through TLS I had to install their certificates in a custom trust store (JKS) loaded by the Java application at startup.

My question is: what happen when one (or more) of these certificates expire? The application stops to connect with the specific service or continues to run logging a warning?

The JKS file is loaded into the application with:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path_to_truststore.jks
```

in a Docker container deployed into a AWS ECS cluster.

I read some online articles and posts on Stackoverflow but I'm still confused.

Here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/308538
seems that the application still works even if the certificate is expired.

> Keep in mind, this certificate may not even be technically valid or it
> can EVEN be self signed and not validated by a Root CA, but if it
> exists on the specified Truststore that has been loaded into the Java
> application then it will still trust it.
>
> What you didn't describe is if this certificate is for a network
> resource that you are providing as a server or a network resource that
> you require as a client. I**f the latter then you might get a warning
> about the certificate being expired, but it will still work because it
> is in your trust store.**

But here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22324010/17982071

I read a different thing.

> If a certificate in the trust store expires, and is not replaces with
> an updated version with the same subject and key, it will be discarded
> for the purpose of building the certification path, so you'll get an
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException (coming from "PKIX path building
> failed...").

Thanks.

Comment: Surely you can just redeploy the truststore?

Comment: @user207421he truststore is embedded into the Docker image when the application is built from the pipeline